# Create/Touch a file on host from docker container

Tags: linux, docker, shell, docker-compose, filesystems

I want to compress some configuration files into a tar and save it on */root/* path on the host.

Currently my code which is running inside the container is creating the tar inside the container and then copying it to the server.

Is there a way that I can directly create the tar on the host from inside the container. A simple example with touch command would also help here.

Comment: Use [volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/)?

Comment: If the primary goal of your process is to create files on the host, it's probably going to be much easier to just not run it in Docker (which _as a design goal_ makes this difficult).

Answer (score 3):

yes, you can mound the host directory, and then run the desired command,

The below will creat tar file and will exit. run the below command from the desired directory.

tree

```
.
└── config
    └── default.conf
```

create tar

```
docker run -it --rm --workdir=/app -v $PWD/:/app alpine sh -c "tar -czvf file.tar.gz config"
```

Tree after execution

```
├── config
│   └── default.conf
└── file.tar.gz
```

**From container to host**

```
docker run -it --rm --workdir=/app -v $PWD/:/app alpine sh -c "mkdir myfiles; cd myfiles; touch hello.txt; cd ..; tar -czvf file.tar.gz myfiles"
```

- it creates myfiles/hello.txt  or it can also be an existing directory
- create tar on host mount location

For existing directory in the container

```
docker run -it --rm --workdir=/app -v $PWD/:/app alpine sh -c "cd parent_directory; tar -czvf file.tar.gz myfiles; cp parent_directory/file.tar.gz /app"
```

**Write tar file onto host**

```
 docker run -it --rm  alpine sh -c "cd path_to_tar ; tar -czf - ." >filename.tar.gz
```

Comment: the folder config (which i want to compress) is not on the host server, its inside the docker container. in your solution, the config should be on the host right?

Comment: Yes it assume in the host, you want compress on inside container and then bring it host?

Comment: Updated @Rishav you can check section from container to host

Comment: Thankyou! But as I mentioned, this is my current logic. taring and copying takes time (x+y time units). I want to tar the files inside the container to directly write into a tar file on the host.

Comment: @Rishav got it. answer updated. you can now write directly to the host

Answer (score 0):

You would need to [mount a volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/). In this case, in your `docker-compose.yml`, specify the volume with the absolute path on your host machine and the corresponding path in the container, e.g.:

```
version: "3"
services:
  my-service:
    build:
      context: ../
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: my-service
    volumes:
      - "/root/:/path/to/container/dist/"
```

Then, in your container, simply write the files to the `/path/to/container/dist/` directory, by doing something like:

```
$ cp my_config.tar /path/to/container/dist/
```

Note that this output path could be anywhere and with any name. Make sure it's a directory specific to this "tunnel" between host and container, otherwise unwanted files may end up written, or you may overwrite other files present in your host's `/root/`.

Comment: can i do this using shell script? can i mount a volume without adding in docker-compose file?

Comment: Yes you could, but you would still be using the `docker-cli` API (wrapped in a shell script).

Comment: Please edit your original question if you need further help.